# How to accumulate facts with same field value in drools

Tags: drools, accumulate

I've written a rule for alerting ssh event with "failed password". This rule is here:

```
rule "Hello World"
  when
    accumulate(m:Message(eventType=="Failed password") over window:time( 59s );s:count(m);s>3)
  then
     System.out.println( "success" );
     Alert alert=new Alert("ssh","test");
     insert(alert);
end
```

This is working for the first scenario. But I want to extend this rule. I want to accumulate ssh event with "failed password" for with the same Src_ip address. For example, if I have 4 failed password ssh event in 59s from three different src_ip, the rule does not match, but when I have 4 failed password ssh event in 59s from one src_ip, rule matches. How I should rewrite this rule for this scenario.

Comment: You speak about some properties (ssh, src_ip) without clear indication to which class they belong. Add the Java classes to your question. - Also, the logic isn't clear. What about 4 failed from events from *two* different src_ip? Or three from one src_ip? Or 10 from three different src_ip? ;-)

Comment: the "then" part of the rule is not important here. my question is related to the "when" part of rule. with this rule if there are 4 ssh events with the type of "failed password" in 59s from any src_ip matches the rule and the "then" part of the rule execute. But I want to rewrite this rule to matches only when 4 ssh events with the type of "failed password" in 59s have the same value in the filed of src_ip.

Comment: with this rule these events fire the rule:
ts:"1:1:1",eventype:"failed password",src_ip:"1.1.1.1"
ts:"1:1:3",eventype:"failed password",src_ip:"1.1.1.1"
ts:"1:1:7",eventype:"failed password",src_ip:"1.1.1.5"
ts:"1:1:9",eventype:"failed password",src_ip:"1.1.1.7"
I want to rewrite rule to fire only with these events:
ts:"1:1:1",eventype:"failed password",src_ip:"1.1.1.1"
ts:"1:1:3",eventype:"failed password",src_ip:"1.1.1.1"
ts:"1:1:7",eventype:"failed password",src_ip:"1.1.1.1"
ts:"1:1:9",eventype:"failed password",src_ip:"1.1.1.1"

Answer (score 0):

You need one Message to pick a certain IP address; then you can accumulate others with the same value.

```
rule "Four or more"
when
   $ml: Message( eventType == "Failed password", $ip: src_ip )
   not Message( eventType == "Failed password", src_ip == $ip, this after $ml )
   accumulate( Message(eventType == "Failed password", src_ip == $ip )
        over window:time( 59s ); s:count(1); s > 3 )
then
   System.out.println( "success" );
   Alert alert=new Alert("ssh","test");
   insert(alert);
 end
```

Comment: this code makes error:
Field Reader does not exist for declaration '$ip' in 'predicate 'eventType == "Failed password"'' in the rule 'sshbrute' : [Rule name='sshbrute']

Field Reader does not exist for declaration '$ip' in 'predicate 'src_ip == $ip'' in the rule 'sshbrute' : [Rule name='sshbrute']

Unable to Analyse Expression src_ip == $ip:
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: com.sample.Message.src_ip()]
[Near : {... src_ip == $ip ....}]

Comment: Perhaps you didn't copy the rule correctly. Which Drools version are you using?

Comment: Works as advertised. Either you made an error in copying or you have some other snag. Edit your question (don't use comments for code etc) adding: (a) the rule as it is now (b) class Message with all declarations for the attributes eventType and src_ip.

Comment: when I rewrite to this form it works: 
ml: Message( eventType == "Failed password")
        not Message( eventType == "Failed password", srcip == ml.srcip, this before ml )
        mesg : Number(doubleValue>3) from accumulate( Message( eventType=="Failed password",srcip==ml.srcip) over window:time( 59s ),count(1) )
why it gets error when I use $ip in first pattern?

Comment: I can't tell you unless you post *exactly* the code causing the error, including the Java class definition for Message.